# Symmetric cipher for integer algorithm/method

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, shuffle

I am looking for a bijective transform that I can use **NOT for encryption**, but for obfuscation. The idea is to take integers such as `1, 2, 3, 4` and project them onto another axis. The main idea is to ensure a maximum distance between two adjacent integers from domain `A` when projected in domain `B`.

I wrote the following in Python, but the target language will be PHP. I don't mind about the implementation, only the algorithm/method matters.

Example for `n = 8`:

```
A     B
0 <-> 4
1 <-> 5
2 <-> 6
3 <-> 0
4 <-> 2
5 <-> 7
6 <-> 3
7 <-> 1
```

One naive implementation would be to build a random one-to-one correspondance table then use as a **O(1)** transform function.

```
a = func(0) # a = 4
b = func(a) # b = 0
```

### Most efficient algorithm

The most efficient algorithm consists of building a hash-table which requires **O(n)** memory and executes in **O(1)**.

```
class Shuffle:
    def __init__(self, n, seed=42):        
        self._table = list(range(n))
        random.seed(seed)
        random.shuffle(self._table)

    def enc(self, n):
        return self._table[n]

    def dec(self, n):
        return self._table.index(n)
```

Unfortunately I am looking for a lighter perhaps simpler algorithm.

### Dumb attempt

Here comes the fun part, because I have tried to play with One-Time-Pad (OTP), some symmetric encryption algorithms (Blowfish) without success. Eventually I tried to play with a dumb funny naive kind of implementation:

```
def enigma(input): # Because why not?
    a = deque([1, 3, 0, 4, 2])
    b = deque([3, 0, 4, 2, 1])
    u = [0 for i in range(len(input))]
    for i, c in enumerate(input):
        u[i] = a.index(b.index([4, 3, 2, 1, 0][b[a[c]]]))
        a.rotate(1)
        b.rotate(3)    
    return u

def shuffle(n, seed=81293): # Because enigma is not enough
    random.seed(seed)
    serie = list(range(len(n)))
    random.shuffle(serie)
    for i, j in enumerate(serie):
        n = n.copy()
        n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
        return n

def int2five(decimal): # Base 10 -> Base 5
    radix = 5
    s = [0 for i in range(9)]
    i = 0
    while (decimal):
        s[i] = decimal % radix
        decimal = decimal // radix
        i += 1
    return list(reversed(s))

def five2int(five): # Base 5 -> Base 10
    return int(''.join([str(x) for x in five]), 5)

def enc(n):
    return five2int(enigma(shuffle(int2five(n))))

def dec(s):
    return five2int(shuffle(enigma(int2five(s))))
```

With as result:

```
>>> ['%d <-> %d' % (i, enc(i)) for i in range(7)]
['0 <-> 1729928',
 '1 <-> 558053',
 '2 <-> 1339303',
 '3 <-> 948678',
 '4 <-> 167428',
 '5 <-> 1729943',
 '6 <-> 558068']
```

Why did I choose base 5? I choose my work range to be `[0..2e6[`, so by looking at the best base to work with that maximise the coverage (yeah that following code is ugly):

```
>>> [(d, l, s, 100 - round(s/n*100,1)) for (d, l, s) in sorted([(k, round(math.log(n, k), 3), n - k**(math.floor(math.log(n, k))) - 1)
        for k in range(2, 100)], key=lambda k: k[2])[0:10]]

[(5, 9.015, 46873, 97.7),
 (18, 5.02, 110430, 94.5),
 (37, 4.018, 125837, 93.7),
 (11, 6.051, 228437, 88.6),
 (6, 8.097, 320382, 84.0),...]
```

I notice that base 5 can be expressed in 9 digits with a coverage of 97% of my range. The second best candidate is base 18 with 94% of the coverage.

Comment: Lot's of text but no questions. I'm a little puzzled  because you started with a 6 or 7 line `class Shuffle`, then dismissed it because you want a *... lighter perhaps simpler algorithm...*, then go on to something 10 times as complex. So I must ask: define "lighter and simpler".

Comment: You could XOR with a small constant.  Why small?  To guarantee that max(project(A) - project(A+1)) is small.

Comment: I think [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418358/given-a-number-produce-another-random-number-that-is-the-same-every-time-and-di/34420445#34420445) solves this problem. It's a simple mathematical transformation. I prefer it to the `xor` method because it's more difficult for the curious to determine the pattern.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I dismissed the first solution because it uses too much memory, the question is to find a solution to this problem that use less memory.

Comment: @JimMischel Not really, because your algorithm uses O(n) memory.

Comment: @nowox My algorithm does not use O(n) memory. Whatever gave you the idea that it does? I suggest you re-read the answer, study the code, and perhaps read the linked article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like you want to use a [Format-Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) here and a good one is FFX from Mihir Bellare (white paper [here](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/proposed-modes/ffx/ffx-spec.pdf)).

As you noticed, you will not find any *simple* algorithm based on rotations that can map a input domain `X` to `Y` with `Y = X` for `f: X->Y` and `X` in any range `[x0..xn]`.

With this kind of format preserving encryption you will need to specify your range as:

```
range = radix ** exponent - 1
```

In your case you chose radix 5 and 9 for the exponent.

### Enciphering using FFX

For the implementation you can use [pyffx](https://github.com/emulbreh/pyffx), an implementation of the Feistel-based encryption (FFX).

```
class Five(pyffx.String):
    def __init__(self, ffx, length, **kwargs):
        super(Five, self).__init__(ffx, '01234', length, **kwargs)

    def pack(self, v):
        return super(Five, self).pack(str(v).zfill(self.length))

    def unpack(self, v, t):
        return int(super(Five, self).unpack(v, t))
```

Then

```
>>> import pyffx
>>> radix, exponent = 5, 9
>>> e = Five(b'secret', exponent)
>>> e.encrypt(123)
321301321
```

### Enciphering on Arbitrary Domains

As mentioned, FFX only enciphers data in a domain specified by `radix ** exponent - 1`. If you wish to encipher on an arbitrary domain, you can use a method named **Cycle Walking** described as:

```
 def cycle_walking (x, encipher) {
   if encipher(x) is an element of M
     return encipher(x)
   else 
     return cycle_walking(encipher(x))
 }
```

For this you need to use a domain N strictly larger than your target domain M.